# compile typescript with a visual studio code task, specifying the output directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this task in visual studio code which compiles my typescript files. I would like to make a cleaner file structure by adding all typescript to one folder and all javascript to another folder. How do I change the args of my task to do that? My current code causes it to compile the output to be in the same folder as the typescript. Here is current code:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": [
        "scripts/front_end/view_models/search_filter_view_model.ts",
        "scripts/front_end/models/area_getter.ts",
         "scripts/front_end/bootstrap_app.ts",
         "scripts/front_end/models/category.ts",
         "scripts/front_end/plugins/slideshow.ts"
    ],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what is happening in your project. But here is what I am using in my tsconfig.json used for my angular projects. You might want to use this as a sample for your project and modify accordingly. `outDir` and `outFile` is what you need I guess.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir":"client/build/",
    "outFile": "client/build/all.js",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "server"
  ],
  "include": [
        "client/*.ts",
        "client/**/*.ts",
        "client/**/**/*.ts"
  ]   
}

// Include all folders to put to a file.
/*    "outDir":"client/build/",
    "outFile": "client/build/all.js" */
```

Comment: Thanks. Is outDir the directory that the js files go in? Is all of your js that came from the ts files put into one file (client/build/all.js)? So your js is all in client/build/all.js?

Comment: `outDir` is the dir where the build of all js files go in. `outFile` is almost the same but the difference is that it contains the bundle (all js files) file name. It contains all the js files converted from ts files mention within the `include` section. The tsconfig.json file path is relative to the folder paths mentioned. so check that when compiling.